# Getting Javascript values from client on page load

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm trying to determine the client window size on pageload, to use in creating a bitmap using c#. From reading on SO and elsewhere, I know that one method would be to:

1. Write a Javascript function to get the relevant values;
2. Store these in hidden fields;
3. Read the value using the code behind (c#) and then do stuff with it.

However, I'm getting tripped up by the execution sequence that runs code behind BEFORE any Javascript, even though I've set `<body onload...` to get and set the relevant values. (see below)

I know the rest of my code works, because, when I execute, the page shows the word "by" and the button. Then, after I have clicked the button and the page reloads, it can now suddenly read the two hidden values.

My question is, how can I get my c# Page_Load code to get those two hidden values from the client side, *before* it executes the rest of my code, and without the need for user action like clicking a button?

My page:

```
<body onload="getScreenSize()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenW" ID="hiddenW" runat="server" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenH" ID="hiddenH" runat="server" />
   <script>
       function getScreenSize() {
           var myW = document.getElementById("hiddenW");
           myW.value = window.innerWidth;
           var myH = document.getElementById("hiddenH");
           myH.value = window.innerHeight;
       }
   </script>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(hiddenW.Value+" by " +hiddenH.Value);
    }

}
```

On first run (when I need those values), it shows

[image]

and after I click the button, it proves the Javascript works:

[image]

The question then, is how do I get those values *before* the rest of my Page_Load code runs, so that I can go straight into generating and displaying my image?

Comment: Use domready event, it fires before window load and all of the data you need is available (window height etc) .. more on this here : http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml

Comment: Please see i have updated my answer to show how to implement this using JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the client window size before the C# `Page_Load()` executes because the page is rendered to the client after the C# code execution is complete.
The window size may change during page load, hence you have to get the window size only after page load is complete.

**Solution**:
You can use ajax to send the values to the back-end, after the page has loaded completely.
**OR**
You can cause a post-back using java-script after you get the correct value, this way:
JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var width = window.innerWidth ||
            document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
            document.body.clientWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight ||
             document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
             document.body.clientHeight;
    $('#hdn_width').val(width);
    $('#hdn_height').val(height);
    $('#your_form').submit();
});
```

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            // Use hdn_width and hdn_height here
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Given that fact, is there a way for me to wait until the page is rendered, get the relevant values, and then (with no user action) continue to execute a block of c# code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

This would solve your problem

`For Example`

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   //Control Initialization
   //Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this needs user action to cause a postback, which I don't want. What's the best way to cause it to happen using code?

Comment: ajax would be a choice with async false

Answer (score 0):

I used a timer to postback once and two none-displayed textboxes to store the window-values width and height. the textboxes are filled with a javascript:

```
document.getElementById('<%=TxWd.ClientID %>').value = window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById('<%=TxHt.ClientID %>').value = window.innerHeight;
```

In code behind (VB.NET):

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Session("seswidth") = Val(TxWd.Text)
    Session("sesheigth") = Val(TxHt.Text)
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```